# How to change display output by software / operating system, rather than display's front panel?

Tags: display

I have a HP V22b display connected to two computers, one using Linux / VGA Output and the other using Windows 10 / Hdmi output. When I want to change display output, so I can use the other computer, I have to do this manually, by hand, from the display's panel, which have difficult accesssing and bad touch buttons.

Is there any way so I could change display output using some kind of software, or command-line command from the operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to transmit display control commands (which are not standardised anyways and thus differ from manufacturer to manufacturer and probably even on different models of the same brand) over a video input.

If your current situation really does not allow you to use your OSD/the display buttons to change your current video source, I suggest looking into KVM-switches (which would eliminate the need for sets of peripherals (keyboard and mice) for each computer as a neat side effect).

Those can be usually placed on or under your desk and will allow some easy manual switching between KVM-controlled devices. There might be even some software to interface the KVM-switch, but that will be only found on some higher priced models.

Comment: wouldnt his display need to support KVM functionality? A quick search online shows no such thing.

Comment: I thought it  would be unmistakable if I talk about "KVM-switches" ^^ - I mean external hardware like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch

Comment: The OP should be made aware that KVMs *sometimes* have problems with HDCP (High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection) handshaking over HDMI and shop accordingly.

Comment: OH i guess I was confused. In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHXTTEVqUq8 it shows that the user has to input something in a menu that has KVM enabled on the display, and I assumed that the display would need to be compliant somehow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Yorik